# Подскажите, какой код будет синтаксически верным (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

```
var x = 12;
var y = 24;
document.write(x+y);
```

Или:

```
var x = "12";
var y = "24";
document.write(Number(x) + Number (y));
```

Эти 2 кода выведут абсолютно одинаковые значения, но мне не понятно, что будет правильнее?

Comment: Если нет явной необходимости определять переменные как строки, то верхний.

Comment: правильнее будет не использовать `document.write` так как он может поломать верстку :) это так для справки )))

Comment: **Синтаксически** верный? Ну так просто запустите оба варианта и посмотрите что получится, зачем по этому поводу вопрос задавать

Comment: Так я уже запустил, и оба варианта выводят одно и то же, но я не знаю, что будет правильнее

Answer (score 2):

JS не является строго типизированным языком, из-за чего имеется отсутствие потребностей в определений типов переменных. Если со слов синтаксиса, то как и сказали, верхний вариант приемлем, но для каждого "хорошего" программиста - второй вариант будет лучше, да и другие люди, которые будут дорабатывать ваш код, сразу поймут что и куда